# Is an immersed submanifold second-countable?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

By general manifold I mean Hausdorff differential manifold not necessarily second-countable. By standard manifold I mean Hausdorff, second-countable differential manifold.

So my question is, we have an injective immersion, ie with a non singular derivative, $\iota\colon M\to N$. Where $M$ is a connected general manifold and $N$ is a standard manifold. Is it true that $M$ is second-countable.

Note that if we take away the connection hypothesis then it is false. If we consider $M$ to be $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ with the horizontal topology, ie open basis of the form ${a}\times U$ with U open set of $(0,1)$; $N$ to be $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ with the standard topology, and $\iota$ to be the identity then it is false.

If we take away the injective hypothesis I think it is also false. I'm not really sure if it can be done, but if it is possible to wind up the long line around $\mathbb S^1$ similar to how we do with $\mathbb R$ it would be a counterexample.

I've been told it can be done with Riemann manifolds. Something like: $N$ has a riemann metric because it is second-countable, $\iota(M)$ has a riemann metric induced by $N$, taking it back to $M$ by $\iota$, you get a metric in $M$ so it has to be second-countable.
However I don't know anything about Riemann Geometry so I'd prefer a pure topological/differential proof.

I'm interested because it allows you in the proof of the Frobenius theorem not to check about second-countable in the manifold you obtain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Warm-up**
In contrast to the winding of $\mathbb R$, it is impossible to  immerse the long line $L$ into the circle $S^1$.
Indeed if you had such an immersion (injective or not) $i:L\to S^1$, it would induce an isomorphism of line  bundles  $T_L \stackrel {\simeq}{\to} i^*T_S$ on $L$.
Since the tangent bundle of $S^1$ is trivial, the same would be true of $i^*T_S$ and then  of $T_L$ .
However Morrow [proved](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-023-02/S0002-9939-1969-0246318-X/S0002-9939-1969-0246318-X.pdf) that $T_L$ is not trivial.

**The general case**
*A non-second-countable manifold $M$ cannot be immersed into a second countable manifold $N$.*
Indeed, if $i:M\to N$ is such an immersion, put a Riemannian structure on the tangent bundle $T(N)$, which is possible since $N$ is paracompact.
The immersion gives rise to an embedding $di:T(M)\hookrightarrow   i^*T(N)$ of vector bundles on $M$, which induces a Riemannian structure on $T(M)$. This Riemannian structure in turn endows $M$ with a metric compatible with its topolgy. However a connected metrizable manifold  is second-countable . Contradiction.
(I have used that second-countability of a connected manifold is equivalent to metrizability or paracompactness:  see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98105/why-are-smooth-manifolds-defined-to-be-paracompact/98124#98124))

**Edit: An alternative proof**
In case $M$ and $N$ have same dimension one can give  a purely topological proof, more in accordance with your wish of avoiding Riemannian structures.
(It suffices to give a riemannless proof of the warm-up) . Here goes:

Recall that the Poincaré-Volterra theorem states that if $i:X\to Y$ is a local homeomorphism with $X$ connected Hausdorff and $Y$ locally compact, locally connected and second-countable, then $X$ is second-countable too.
If $M$ and $N$ have the same dimension , an immersion $i:M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism and *a fortiori* a local homeomorphism. The theorem of Poincaré-Volterra thus proves that it is impossible to have both $M$ not second- countable and $N$ second-countable.

[Poincaré-Volterra's theorem is the very last result in the first chapter of Bourbaki's *Topology*.
It is  used, for example,  in the proof of [Radó's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rad%C3%B3%27s_theorem_%28Riemann_surfaces%29) according to which every Riemann surface is  second-countable.]

Comment: Morrow's article is fabulous!  I wasn't aware of this (surprisingly easy) result.  Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea about the main question?

Comment: Dear @Gabriel,  well, yes: it is the same as what you were told  .  I have written  down  a complete proof in an edit and given a purely topological proof in the equidimensional case.