# Differentiable Manifold Hausdorff, second countable

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Why do we generally require that a differentiable manifold be Hausdorff and second countable? Is this universally accepted in the definition? My Professor only required the Hausdorff condition for example, but most book I have read require both. Thanks

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but have you heard about [the long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29)? It is the canonical example of a “manifold” which is not second countable. If you look at the wikipedia article you will see some odd behaviour when you try to put a differentiable structure on it.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the response.

Comment: No, it’s not universal: some people study non-metrizable manifolds. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/98105/12042) and its answers, and the accepted answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121403/12042) should go a long way towards answering your question.

Comment: It is fairly common to require paracompactness instead of second-countability (it can be shown that a manifold is paracompact iff each connected component is second-countable).

Answer (score 1):

Those conditions provide the metrizability of the manifold. That is we want a metric space as a result. Actually we want to produce a Riemannian manifold. Some texts require paracompactness, which provides partitions of unity and helps to define a Riemannian metric. Look at Urysohn metrizatiın theorem and other metrization theorems, you will see that these conditions are in their hypothesis.