# Why second countable for definition of manifold?

Tags: general-topology

What is the motivation to define a manifold to be second countable? What kind of pedagogical issues does this avoid?

Comment: It’s not a pædagogical issue: the condition is intended to exclude such locally Euclidean spaces as the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29), which lack some otherwise highly desirable properties (like paracompactness).

Comment: Asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341080/differentiable-manifold-hausdorff-second-countable), but it only generated a few comments.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much @BrianM.Scott, and T.Bongers

Comment: Paritions of unity are a very useful tool to study manifolds, they allow to patch together local entities to make them global. If a manifold were non-second countable, the existence of such partitions would be not guaranteed.