# Why is every one dimensional Complex Manifold paracompact?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, paracompactness

I read on the page
[Why are smooth manifolds defined to be paracompact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98105/why-are-smooth-manifolds-defined-to-be-paracompact)
in one of the answers that every one dimensional complex manifold is automatically paracompact, i.e. there is no complex analogue to the real long line.
My problem: I cant find any book or paper explaining me why this should be the case. In most textbooks, a complex manifold is defined to be paracompact even if this was not necessary in this case.

So: Why is every one dimensional Complex Manifold paracompact?

Comment: This is Radó's theorem. You can find a proof on page 186 of Forster's magnificent [Lectures on Riemann Surfaces](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Lectures_on_Riemann_Surfaces.html?id=iDYBTCVCO_IC) .

Comment: You are welcome, Tom.