# Can there be a manifold with uncountable genus? Can they be compact?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, infinity

Just some random thoughts I had after coming across this paper on Riemann Surfaces of Infinite Genus: [http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/papers/allriem.pdf]

I'm reasonable convinced that $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot have uncountably many regions (of non-zero measure) removed, but I don't quite see that this ruins the potential for manifolds which can be sometimes a lot more whacky than $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Do the Homotopy Groups or Holonomy Groups or the Cohomology Groups still make any sense in this context?  I think they'd have infinitely many generators, which would get strange.

Comment: A compact manifold has finitely generated (co)homology groups, so a well-defined, finite Euler characteristic.

Comment: The pdf link isn't working for some reason.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 Try going here: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/papers/ and looking for the link: allriem.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly strange about homotopy groups or homology groups having a countable infinity of generators (unless the manifold is compact, as said in the comment of @LordSharktheUnknown).

For example the ladder surface is the boundary of a regular neighborhood in $\mathbb R^3 = \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R$ of 
$$\bigl((\mathbb R \times \{0,1\}) \cup (\mathbb Z \times [0,1])\bigr)  \times \{0\}
$$ 
The ladder surface has countably generated $\pi_1$ and $H_1$, but neither is finitely generated. Perhaps an even simpler example is $\mathbb R^2$ minus the radius $1/3$ balls centered at the points of $\mathbb Z \times \{0\}$.

Here's a general fact along these lines. Connected smooth manifolds are usually required by definition to be [paracompact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98105/why-are-smooth-manifolds-defined-to-be-paracompact) (this is unnecessary for Riemann surfaces, which are *proved* to be paracompact by [Rado's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683452/why-is-every-one-dimensional-complex-manifold-paracompact)). One can then use a partition of unity argument to prove that there is a "good open covering" by open sets homeomorphic to balls which is locally finite and such that any finite subset of the covering intersects in either the empty set or a subset homeomorphic to a ball. By applying combination theorems (e.g. Van Kampen's theorem for $\pi_1$ and the Mayer Vietoris theorem for $H_n$, perhaps coupled with direct limit arguments) one can then conclude that $\pi_1$ and each $H_n$ have countable generating sets (any of them could, nonetheless, still be finitely generated). By applying somewhat deeper combination theorems one can also prove that the higher homotopy groups $\pi_n$ have countable generating sets.

Comment: It's nice to know that for a surface, being 'tame' (homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary) is equivalent to $\pi_1$ being finitely generated is equivalent to $H_1$ being finitely generated. But it is a nice exercise to try to think about $\pi_1$ of $S^2$ minus a Cantor set.