# Examples of non-paracompact spaces appearing naturally

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

In the book *Differential Topology* by Morris W. Hirsch, he claims:

> Non-paracompact manifolds never appear naturally.

What are some example of non-paracompact manifolds (or spaces) that do appear naturally?

(The long line for example seems to only be used for counterexamples so it's irrelevant to this question)

Comment: More generally, any nonmetrisable manifold must fail to be paracompact.

Comment: It is a bit vague to say that something does *never appear naturally*. However, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98105 to understand the reasons for requiring paracompactness.

Comment: @Tyrone But do those appear naturally? I'm looking at examples where this kind of space appears naturally. I am aware that *appear naturally* is a big vague that's why i added the tag soft-question.

Comment: What is the definition of "*appearing naturally*" ?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: So, why is the long line not appearing naturally? BTW, I researched in set-theoretic topology. We never talked about something appearing naturally.

Comment: I recommend to read the excellent survey article "The Theory of Nonmetrizable Manifolds" by Peter Nyikos in the Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology. In particular, section 3 contains a lot of examples, so everyone can decide by him-/herself whether one of these "appears naturally".